FCM HTTP v1 api throws permission denied
We are migrating from FCM Legacy to FCM V1 api.
we were using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
with Authorization key={key}
Now Im trying to use https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/messages:send
with Authorization Bearer {accessToken}
Im getting missing IAM permission error cloudmessaging.messages.create
I got the access token using this
GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
credential.createScoped(Set.of("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));
credential.refresh();
credential.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();

My question is I already used this same project apikey to send FCM message using FCM Legacy api but im not sure why v1 api throws missing permission error.

I think you need to add another scope to your credential, and it may be as simple as having it end with the permission you want, but I'm not sure. I'm working through a different route and ended up adding a role to my service account. Good luck.
